# How to resolve Fortify scan reports cannot dereference null pointer exception in Silverlight.js file?

Tags: silverlight

I am getting the following error when trying to run fortify scan on my silverlight project.

The method createObject() in Silverlight.js can dereference a null pointer on line 2,
thereby raising a NullExcpetion.

This silverlight.js file is created by Microsoft. Does anybody have pointers on how this can be resolved?

Comment: Can you post the code? It could be a theoretical error rather than an actual one.

Comment: This is the file that we use. http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/silverlightjs/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4148

Comment: Given that it's "official" Microsoft code I would think the code is OK. Unfortunately the `.js` file is minified (to a certain degree) and all the code is on one line so it's difficult to see what the actual error could be. Check the `.debug.js` file.

Comment: Thanks for your update Chris. Yes.. But our organization would like to have these fixed too. Can you point me to any location where there is information on how fortify scan exceptions can be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the file has come from Microsoft I would assume that the error is theoretical rather than actual. Checking the debug version of the file for `CreateObject` I find the following code:

```
Silverlight.createObject = function(source, parentElement, id, properties, events, initParams, userContext)
{
    var slPluginHelper = new Object();
    var slProperties = properties;
    var slEvents = events;

    slPluginHelper.version = slProperties.version;
    slProperties.source = source;    
    slPluginHelper.alt = slProperties.alt;
    ...
```

I can only assume that fortify is objecting to the following line:

```
    slPluginHelper.version = slProperties.version;
```

as `slProperties` *could* be null if the `properties` argument is null.

If you really must have these errors fixed then you need to report the issue to Microsoft and hope that they release an updated version of the file. In the meantime you could modify the code (edit the `.debug` version of the file) and use that. However, you will have to reapply your edits if you download a new version of the file at any point in the future.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I had to replace c = l with if (!l) c = l; else c = ""; in Silverlight.js file and the fortify scan ran successfully.